# LARAVEL query error 'SELECT count() as aggregate from posts where posts . deleted_at is null'

Tags: php, laravel

So this is my first time trying to deploy my first laravel project to a shared hosting.

What I do is basically make a folder in my shared hosting root folder and copy everything in my laravel project except the public folder.

After it completed, I copied all of the public folder file and copied it to `public_html` in my shared hosting.

Then I edited the index.php on public_html file to point to the right directory and edited the .env file for database configuration. I also already imported my database from my local machine.

After that I tried to open my website and it shows me this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'darrowxy_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null)

I tried to open my login pages and it worked perfectly, but when I tried to login it also give me similar error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'darrowxy_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = lionel.ritchie@yahoo.com
>   limit 1)

I've been searching for the solution over the internet but nothings worked.

I only have one main controller that handle the CRUD, and the error told me that the errors are on my index function in the controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(8); //it points to this

    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Any help appreciated, Thank you ^^

Comment: there's no way that the error is on that code because you're not even using `select count(*)` on your query. and for access denied you should check your privilege on your database user.

Comment: yes, that's why I am so confused right now. I already checked my database privilege and it's all good.

Comment: do you have a code on your controller that use `select count(*)`?

Comment: ohh nevermind its all about `access denied`

Comment: Try removing `/bootstap/cache/config.php`

Answer (score 0):

Your current use that you have setup can not access the mysql database you are trying to connect to. You need to check your .env file for DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_CONNECTION (which should default to mysql).

so for instance, in a test environment mine our

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

which work in my local homestead environment. when I change my user or password I get this.

[image]

that image looks awfully familiar. So I think we can be sure your user or password that you are attempting to connect to the database are incorrect. If that is not the issue you are trying to connect to a different mysql db instance that does not have your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you config your ENV properly.
If so please try to run php artisan config:clear to reload your env config.

Answer (score 0):

maybe some of the model files haven't been changed according to the database name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).